# Есть ли поддержка ротации секретов в Yandex облаке?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yandex-cloud

В AWS есть [поддержка](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html) ротации секретов, есть ли аналогичный функционал для yandex облака?

Answer (score 0):

В Яндексе есть сервис "**Yandex Secret Manager**" аналогичный амазоновскому.